# 's' character being highlighted in VIM

Tags: unix, vim

I was trying some commands to show and replace white space characters but now every time I open VIM, It highlights all 's' characters in file. How do I disable it?

Comment: `\s` is the shorthand for "whitespace". Maybe you have changed a few settings here and there that deal with `verymagic` or `magic`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:set nohls
```

will turn off search highlighting.  The search pattern is untouched and the next search pattern will not be highlighed (unless you `:set hls` to turn it back on).

```
:let @/ = ''
```

will empty the search pattern, so nothing will be highlighted.  Another search will set the search pattern and be highlighted as expected.

And, as another answer states,

```
:noh
```

temporarily turns off `hls` — at least until the next search.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely residual search highlighting.  turn it off until the next search with `:noh`.